# CSS Drop down list does not stay open on hover

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've searched the web for an answer to my problem but I couldn't find any good solutions.

I am trying to create a drop down list that shows up when the mouse is hovering over an icon. That works, but when I try to select an option in the drop down list it just dissapears. I can't figure out how to make it stay when i move the pointer from the "icon div" to the "list div". A problem I found many people encountered was that the "list div" wasn't close enough to the "icon div" or menu. I cheched this by setting different backgrounds and from what I can tell they are even overlapping.

I'll give you the code:

```
.settings_list {
    height: 25px;
    width: 39px;
    position: fixed; top: 26px; right: 7px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    background: transparent url('resources/img/icons/list.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.settings_list:hover {
    background-image: url('resources/img/icons/list_light.png');
}

.settings_list_sub {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #999;
    opacity: 0.70;
}

.settings_list:hover + .settings_list_sub {
    display: block; 
}

.settings_list_sub li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.settings_list_sub li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #999;
    width: 135px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.settings_list_sub li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FCFCFC;
    background-color: #06C;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="settings_list"></div>
<div class="settings_list_sub">
    <li><a href="">Test01</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Log out</a></li>
</div>
```

Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong. If you could help me I would be very grateful!

I actually have one more question. Is it possible to make my icon clickable (to open the drop-down list) without using JS?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a start your HTML is invalid. `li` tags must be children of a `ul` or `ol` tag

Comment: I just noticed. Done! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add:

```
.settings_list_sub:hover{
     display:block;
}
```

to your code and it works :)

Comment: Haha great! I just did that and resized "settings_list" -div.

Comment: @user2212773 ,I almost downvoted, but i rather explain why i was about to, HTML is not valid, it should be fixed no matter that cascasde is applied. cheers